# What does gets() save when it reads just a newline

Tags: c, stdin, gets

Here's the description of `gets()` from Prata's *C Primer Plus*:

> It gets a string from your system's standard input device, normally
>   your keyboard. Because a string has no predetermined length, `gets()`
>   needs a way to know when to stop. Its method is to read characters
>   until it reaches a newline (`\n`) character, which you generate by
>   pressing the Enter key. It takes all the characters up to (but not
>   including) the newline, tacks on a null character (`\0`), and gives the
>   string to the calling program.

It got my curious as to what would happen when `gets()` reads in just a newline. So I wrote this:

```
  int main(void)
  {
    char input[100];

    while(gets(input))
    {
      printf("This is the input as a string: %s\n", input);
      printf("Is it the string end character? %d\n", input == '\0');
      printf("Is it a newline string? %d\n", input == "\n");
      printf("Is it the empty string? %d\n", input == "");
    }

    return 0;
  }
```

Here's my interaction with the program:

```
$ ./a.out
This is some string
This is the input as a string: This is some string
Is it the string end character? 0
Is it a newline string? 0
Is it the empty string? 0

This is the input as a string:
Is it the string end character? 0
Is it a newline string? 0
Is it the empty string? 0
```

The second block is really the thing of interest, when all I press is enter.  What exactly is `input` in that case? It doesn't seem to be any of my guesses of: `\0` or `\n` or `""`.

Comment: You can't compare strings with `==`; you need to use `strcmp`. (Or you can say `input[0] == '\n'` and `input[0] == '\0'`.)

Comment: You can't compare strings and chars , `input == '\0'` should be `*input == '\0'`

Comment: Oh, and `input == '\0'` is equivalent to `input == 0`.

Comment: Augment the warning level of your compiler. It should have told you that you are comparing a pointer to an integer and that `gets` is deprecated.

Comment: **Never** use [`gets(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gets.3.html).

Comment: There is no longer any function called `gets()`, it has been removed from the C language. Therefore, studying said function is of limited use. Focus on using and understanding `fgets()` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This part in the description of `gets` might be confusing:

> It takes all the characters up to (but not including) the newline

It might be better to say that it *takes* all the characters **including** the newline but *stores* all characters **not including** the newline.

So if the user enters `some string`, the `gets` function will read `some string` and the newline character from the user's terminal, but store only `some string` in the buffer - the newline character is lost. This is good, because no one wants the newline character anyway - it's a control character, not a part of the data that user wanted to enter.

Therefore, if you only press <kbd>enter</kbd>, `gets` interprets it as an empty string. Now, as noted by some people, your code has multiple bugs.

---

> `printf("This is the input as a string: %s\n", input);`

No problem here, though you might want to delimit your string by some artificial characters for better debugging:

> `printf("This is the input as a string: '%s'\n", input);`

---

> `printf("Is it the string end character? %d\n", input == '\0');`

Not good: you want to check 1 byte here, not the whole buffer. If you try to compare the whole buffer with 0, the answer is always `false` because the compiler converts `\0` to `NULL` and interprets the comparison like "does the buffer exist at all?".

The right way is:

> `printf("Does the first byte contain the string end character? %d\n", input[0] == '\0');`

This compares just 1 byte to `\0`.

---

> `printf("Is it a newline string? %d\n", input == "\n");`

Not good: this compares the address of the buffer with the address of `"\n"` - the answer is always `false`. The right way to compare string in C is `strcmp`:

> `printf("Is it a newline string? %d\n", strcmp(input, "\n") == 0);`

Note the peculiar usage: `strcmp` returns 0 when the strings are equal.

---

> `printf("Is it the empty string? %d\n", input == "");`

The same bug here. Use `strcmp` here too:

> `printf("Is it the empty string? %d\n", strcmp(input, "") == 0);`

---

BTW as people always say, `gets` cannot be used in a secure way, because it doesn't support protection from buffer overflow. So you should use [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead, even though it's less convenient:

```
char input[100];
while (fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin))
{
    ...
}
```

This leads to possible confusion: `fgets` doesn't delete the newline byte from the input it reads. So if you replace `gets` in your code by `fgets`, you will get different results. Fortunately, your code will illustrate the difference in a clear way.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation

Answer (score 3):

It sets the string to `""`, that is, `{'\0'}`.  Don’t use `gets()`, though. It causes buffer overflows.

Comment: But it stores them “not including” the newline.

Comment: indeed, my fault ... this happens when never using `gets()` ;)

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense