# Program Crashes?

Tags: c, string, for-loop, crash

I'm new in programming and I picked up this as a hobby. So I started solving an exercise but my program crashes unexpectedly.
This is the exercise:

> The Sensitive Society Club organizes a donation campaign. To put more fun in the campaign, they organize a competition among departments. In the competition top donating students and the department are awarded with a certificate.
>
> **Question:** Write a program that reads the information for n students then it shows the name of the student who donated the most amount and the department whose average is the highest.
>
> **Input specification:** You will be given one integer (n) in the beginning. Then, the following n lines will have three information:
>
> **Student name:** names are at most 20 char strings containing only 26 English (uppercase or lowercase) letters his/her department: at most 4 chars long string (only 3 departments in the competition: CEN, ECE or BINF)
>
> **Output specification**: Show two strings :
> The name of the student who donated the most,
> The department whose average is the highest.

```
int n,i,CENc=0,ECEc=0,BINFc=0,CENa=0,ECEa=0,BINFa=0,amountS,amountH=0,avgCEN,avgECE,avgBINF;
char department[4],name[20],nameH[20];
scanf ("%d",&n);
for (i=0;i<n;i++);{
    gets (name);
    gets (department);
    scanf("%d",&amountS);
    if (strcmp(department,"ECE")==0){
        ECEa=ECEa+amountS;
        ECEc++;
    }
     else if (strcmp(department,"CEN")==0){
        CENa=CENa+amountS;
        CENc++;
    }
     else if (strcmp(department,"BINF")==0){
        BINFa=BINFa+amountS;
        BINFc++;
    }
     if (amountS>amountH){
            amountH=amountS;
            strcpy(nameH,name);
     }

}
avgCEN=CENa/CENc;
avgECE=ECEa/ECEc;
avgBINF=BINFa/BINFc;
 if (avgCEN>avgECE && avgCEN>avgBINF){
    printf("%d", avgCEN);
    printf("%s", nameH);
 }
 else if (avgECE>avgCEN && avgECE>avgBINF){
    printf("%d", avgECE);
    printf("%s", nameH);
 }
 else if (avgBINF>avgCEN && avgBINF>avgECE){
    printf("%d", avgBINF);
    printf("%s", nameH);
 }
  return 0
```

So i know it's a little badly done but here's the problem.
I enter the first and second line of inputs `Johnny CEN 500` `Mark BINF 600` and the program crashes after that.
Any thoughts on why that happens?  Note: I would not like to use arrays at this time as I am  learning the basics and moving on with time to more complicated stuff.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your code can't be compiled as-is, so it's going to be much harder for people to help you.

Comment: `department[4]`. Strings in C contain a NUL terminator. So "BINF" requires 5 `chars` in the array to store.

Comment: And never use `gets`. It even tells you that in the [gets manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/gets).

Comment: " I would not like to use arrays at this time". `department[4],name[20],nameH[20]` You do realise these are arrays?

Comment: I know the code is mess , but please write question neatly , refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You Enter as Second Input `Mark BINF 600` , Now Department is only have 4 characters including Null Character `\0` . So please change `char department[4]` to `char department[5]`.

Also From This Answer From [What does gets() save when it reads just a newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32757162/what-does-gets-save-when-it-reads-just-a-newline) On Working of `gets()`.

This part in the description of `gets` might be confusing:

> It takes all the characters up to (but not including) the newline
>
> > It might be better to say that it *takes* all the characters **including** the newline but *stores* all characters **not including** the newline.
> >
> > So if the user enters `some string`, the `gets` function will read `some string` and the newline character from the user's terminal, but store only `some string` in the buffer - the newline character is lost. This is good, because no one wants the newline character anyway - it's a control character, not a part of the data that user wanted to enter.
> >
> > Therefore, if you only press <kbd>enter</kbd>, `gets` interprets it as an empty string.

And So On The Start on your line `scanf ("%d",&n)` , when you type the input and press enter , the new line character is stored in the buffer so when the execution arrives on `gets (name)` , `gets` read the new line character and interpret the string as empty and move forward , so to digest that new line character you could well do this ,

```
 char a ;
 scanf("%d" , &n);
 scanf("%c" , &a);
```

So the new line character that is present in buffer will get stored in a , and will not be read by `gets`.

Also If you are giving input on a line like `Johnny CEN 500` , then `gets()` is probably storing all of it in a single string , because it does count white space. So You probably do not want that.

Also Somewhere In This Part of Code You Are Probably Dividing By `0`.

```
  avgCEN=CENa/CENc;  
  avgECE=ECEa/ECEc;  
  avgBINF=BINFa/BINFc;
```